# AJAX security and user managment

Tags: php, ajax, security

I am working on a web application that will be hosted on a server that is "on the internet", not a LAN.

The app uses quite a bit of AJAX calls and has about 12 ajax handler files for the functions.

My question is instead of asking anybody here to write a tutorial on AJAX security, does anybody know of any good resources (website, book, whatever) that can help me with securing these files.

Right now, as long as you know the variable name its looking for you can freely get data from the database.

I was thinking maybe session validation, or something along those lines for the logged in user.

Anyways if you have any good resources I'll do the homework myself.

Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by this "Right now, as long as you know the variable name its looking for you can freely get data from the database."

Comment: also, you can use the PHP `$_SESSION` id on the files you access with ajax, just be sure to put `session_start()` at the top of the php file

Comment: @Johnny you can make a fake request and send it to ajax_file.php?id=32122&action=delete (for demonstration purposes) and it will delete row 32122 or whatever... I haven't made it validate where the request is coming from..

Comment: you need to use a `$_SESSION` cookie to validate the user. the session cookie is valid until the user fully closes the browser.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls are generally used to access web services, which is what it seems you are using them for here. If that is the case then what you need to be concerned about is the security layer that you have provided in the server-side scripting language you are using (looks like you are using PHP as per your question's tags).

The same way that you do authentication and protection for other pages on your site that aren't accessed via AJAX calls you can implement for your web services. For instance, if you require authentication for your application then you can store the user's ID in $_SESSION. From there you can check to make sure the user is logged in via $_SESSION whenever one of your web services is requested.

Comment: wow ok, that is way more simple than i thought it would be lol. I will start experiementing tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource. [Securing Ajax Applications: Ensuring the Safety of the Dynamic Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529317)

However a very simple method is to use a MD5 hash with a private key.  e.g. USER_NAME+PRIVATE_KEY.  If you know the users name on the website/login you can provide that key in an MD5 hash set to a javascript variable.  Then simply pass the users name in your AJAX request and the REST service can just take the same private key plus the users name and compare the two hashes.  You're simply sending across a hash, and the user name then.  It's simple and effective.  Virtually impossible to reverse too unless you have a simple private key.

So in your javascript you might have this set:

```
var user='username';
var hash='925c35bae29a5d18124ead6fd0771756'
```

Then, when you send your request you send something like this:

```
myService.php?user=username&hash=925c35bae29a5d18124ead6fd0771756&morerequests=goodthings
```

When you check it, in the service you would do something like this

```
<?php
if(md5($_REQUEST['user']."_privatekey")==$_REQUEST['hash']){
echo 'passed validation';
}else{
echo 'sorry charlie';
}?>
```

Obviously you would need to use PHP or something else to generate the hash with the private key, but I think you get the general idea.  _privatekey should be something complex in the event you do have a troll that tries to hack it.

Comment: I wrote a program with hashing before, and was thinking about trying to find some type of way to hash data to make it not very guessable.. I will read that resource tomorrow as well.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen AJAX calls that check the `X-REQUESTED-WITH` HTTP header to "verify" that the request originated from AJAX. Depending on how you're sending your AJAX calls (with `XmlHttpRequest` or a JS library), you can either use the standard value for this header, or set it to a custom value. That way, you can do something similar to this in PHP to check if the page was requested with AJAX:

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

```
if( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

It is important to note that since it's an HTTP header, it can be spoofed, so it is by no means full-proof.